# Can I use download-archive command to only download new uploads?

Tags: youtube-dl

I am trying to download just new videos. I realize I need to populate the downloads.txt with the video id's of previously downloaded files.

I have attempted exporting a .JSOn and simple powershell output but nothing is working. The .JSON .info.json file never gets created and Powershell does not record output from other softwares.

Also I am on Windows so there is no TEE and Grep command.

How can I only download new videos from a playlist and not the last 500?

Answer (score 0):

So presently I run the following command in powershell to get just the Video ID's (should work in Command Prompt as well):

```html
$YouTubeChannelUrl = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the Channel URL'
C:\Video_Archive\Youtube-DL_Scripts\youtube-dl --get-id --ignore-errors $YouTubeChannelUrl
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Then I take copy the output to Notepad++ and prepend it with youtube and a space. Then I take that text and add it to the downloads.txt.

A bit of a manual process but definitely speeds up the checking for new downloads.